# error: unable to create directory for .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/development

Tags: git

Try to execute this command in the console:

```
git fetch && git checkout development
```

It shows me this error:

> ```
> error: unable to create directory for .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/development
> From bitbucket.org:camburvenezuela/desiredome
>  ! [new branch]      development -> origin/development  (unable to update local ref)
>
> error: unable to create directory for .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/master
>  ! [new branch]      master     -> origin/master  (unable to update local ref)
> ```

In bitbucket, I believe my branch `development` and believes when he told me to execute this command `git fetch && git checkout development` or did and displays the error:

> ```
> error: unable to create directory for .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/development
> From bitbucket.org:camburvenezuela/desiredome
>  ! [new branch]      development -> origin/development  (unable to update local ref)
>
> error: unable to create directory for .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/master
>  ! [new branch]      master     -> origin/master  (unable to update local ref)
> ```